# Flash Player Plugin on Firefox will not update on Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit

Tags: 11.10, firefox, flash, plugins

I am running on Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit, and my flash player plug-in for Firefox is outdated. I must update my plug-in to flash player 11, but I am not able. I have already installed Adobe Flash Player via Ubuntu Software center (As it prompted me to after trying to download from the Adobe site) Without the plug-in updated, videos can not be played from directly on a Facebook page, and I believe that it distorts the video player on Youtube. (Image of player can be seen at imgur.com/gYbFx)

Comment: @EliahKagan No upvoted answers, and the one that likely will help [is invalid right now](http://askubuntu.com/a/124101/169736)

Comment: My suggestion: **Do not reopen this question:** It's no longer relevant and all the answers are hopelessly outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Then, open up a YouTube video, **right-click** on the video itself and click on **Settings**.

**Uncheck** the "Enable hardware acceleration" checkbox in the **Display** tab.

Your Flash video should now work.

Comment: Neither command worked, saying that my plug-in was up to date when I know it is not. I was unable to reach the "settings" after right clicking the video on YouTube, the choices consisted of file, edit, view, movie control, and help none of which contained a display tab or check box for "enable hardware acceleration."

Comment: It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I did this for Ubuntu 11.10. Download google chrome(not chromium but chrome from google, not the repos), find where the flash file for chrome is located in your directory, it's called "libgcflashplayer.so". Copy it to your desktop and change the name to "libflashplayer.so". Find where Mozilla Firefox keeps the Flash file for Firefox in your directory and replace it with the one you just changed the name of. To replace it I used rootnautilus, drag and drop, just type in gksudo nautilus in terminal.
 It worked for me. I even replaced it with an archived version of adobe flash 9 and it worked, but the version in Chrome is 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this add-on on firefox :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/

After installation, click on "quickmode" and "install stable flash". It will open your terminal, remove the old version and install the new one.

This fixed my problem. Good luck!

Comment: This fixed my problem too!

Comment: This add-on has been removed by its author.